# How to perform CRS Transformation to layers from the built-in python console in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I'm trying to automate some tasks in Qgis, using the built-in python console. I have around 20 layers with different CRS, which I would all like to have the same one.

I'm not sure how to approach this. The cookbook (https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/crs.html) only gives information about how to transform a single point, but I assume it will be somewhat similar.

This is from point transformation from the cookbook:

```
crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)    # WGS 84
crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32633)  # WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)

pt1 = xform.transform(QgsPoint(18,5))
print "Transformed point:", pt1
```

Comment: I think this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/221538/167243) by @Joseph might help you.  

If you just want to change the crs of a layer in your project and not save it in the layer you can do this :  `layer_crs = layer.crs()  layer_crs.createFromString("EPSG:32633")  layer.setCrs(layer_crs)`